# terminator terminal issue are F12 quake mode hide

Tags: 12.04, command-line, terminator

I was installing a file from the terminal and then hit F12 to minimize the terminal so I could get access to a text file.  After I obtained the needed information, I hit F12 but the terminal wouldn't appear.  The top bar said Terminator but no matter what I did it wouldn't visually appear.  I ended up having to open another instance of the terminal reboot and not make that mistake again.

Is there a way to get the terminal to appear in a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have simply killed the process like so... (often useful)

```
sudo pkill -9 terminator
```

Back to the terminator problem... Did you right click on it to try to maximize it, did you accidently use roll-up instead? (roll-up has gotten me)

Comment: I didn't want to kill it since I had something running.  I went to the options and put it on full screen and it didn't show.  What is roll up?  How do you turn it on and off so I can test to see if that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Very useful to unmark the "Hide from taskbar" option. Allows to gain access to your terminal from taskbar or tasklist when F12 pressed and Terminator doesn't show up.